# Can I have mysql queries inside an AJAX post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I initially wrote the contents of the `onreadystatechange` function as an `if $_POST[]` conditional to communicate with a hidden form on my main HTML page, but I was having issues with refreshing the page so I tried to just incorporate `AJAX`. Now my main page stops running my js scripts when it touches this function:

```
 $('#submitIFC').click(function(e) {

 var request;

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if ((request.readyState===4) &&(request.status===200))  {

    $Opinion= $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');

                // The data arrives as a comma-separated string,
        // so we extract each post ids:

        $data=explode(',',str_replace('li','',$Opinion));

        // Getting the number of objects
        list($tot_objects) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sort_objects"));

        if(count($data)!=$tot_objects) die("Wrong data!");

        foreach($data as $k=>$v)
        {
            // Building the sql query:
            $str[]='('.(int)$v.','.($tot_objects-$k).')';
        }

        $str = 'VALUES'.join(',',$str);

        // This will limit voting to once a day per IP:
        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO `sort_votes` (ip,date_submit,dt_submit,Opinion)
                        VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',NOW(),NOW())",'$Opinion');

        //  If the user has not voted before today:
        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            mysql_query('   INSERT INTO `sort_objects` (id,votes) '.$str.'
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE votes = votes+VALUES(votes)');
        }

    e.preventDefault();
    }//end of if
    }//end of onreadystatechange function    


//asynchronously send vote to php file which will send to the server
request.open("POST", "connect.php", true);
request.send();
});
```

If it helps to bring clarity, this function is triggered by this button in my HTML:

```
    <div class="button-holder">
       <?php if(!$voted):?><a href="" id="submitPHC" class="button">Submit Poll<span></span></a><?php endif;?>
        <a href="?results" class="button">View The Results<span></span></a>
     </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you realize that php and JavaScript do not run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In your first part of code you have mixed both client side code i.e javascript and server side code i.e php. Those two do not run at same time. As per your question title why will anybody give a security loop whole in code by sending mysql query through front end. Use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*.  To run your code send request from front end to back end and then run the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate you client code and server code.

Database interaction should be strictly in server side so that clients cant see it.

step 1.
use javascript / jquery to collect information the server needs and send it to server using ajax. using ajax's success: function(data) to perform what ever actions you requires after the server is finished

step 2: 
The server code gets the information, and does all the processing. If, else, while, insert, update delete. When done you can return data to your javascript using echo json_encode(array('data'=>'success')); or what ever you would like your data do be

step 3:
the ajax success function recieves this information and updates the webpage as requied

```
success: function(data){
    var d = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(d.data === 'success'){
        //update stuff
    }
}
```